# Выписать цифры числа в обратном порядке

Tags: c++, алгоритм

У меня есть натуральное число `n`, как можно вывести его цифры в обратном порядке?

Comment: Судя по всему, вы пытались спасти [этот вопрос-ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/758488/revisions), перезадав его ещё раз и дав код и подробные комментарии. В других обстоятельствах думаю, это был бы хороший ответ и отличная закрывашка, но.. вы выбрали не очень подходящий объект для спасения. На so не любят студентов-халявщиков, которые сидя на экзамене гуглят ответы или задают их в прямом эфире, фотографируя вопросы. Предлагаю вам сконцентрироваться на более подходящих вопросах и не негативить по поводу того, что за ваши добржые желания ответили минусами в репутацию.

Comment: @AK я не пытался спасти тот вопрос, просто я на него ответил и сразу стало понятно что через некоторое время вопрос будет автоматически удалён. Мне лишь не хотелось терять мой ответ, поэтому я задал этот вопрос и он точно не будет автоматически удалён, независимо от рейтинга (из-за галочки). В итоге среди моих вопросов этот вопрос занимает третье место по числу просмотров, по-моему это очень классно.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Например с помощью цикла [`while`](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/while), который выглядит так:

```
while (условие) {
    // код, который будет выполняться пока условие истинно
}
```

Таким образом, возможное решение задачи выписывания цифр числа в обратном порядке:

```
int x;
// получаем значение переменной x
// например считаем с клавиатуры, вот так:
// cin >> x;

// выписываем цифры числа по одной, начиная с конца
// в конце каждой итерации удаляем последнюю цифру числа
while (x > 0) {
    // получаем последнюю цифру числа используя оператор взятия остатка от деления
    int last_number = x % 10;
    cout << last_number;
    // удаляем последнюю цифру числа используя оператор целочисленного деления
    x /= 10;
}
```

[Пример работы для числа 268670](https://ideone.com/ImDb1R)

Answer (score 1):

```
int x = ...;

auto s = std::to_string(x);
s.assign(s.rbegin(), s.rend());
std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

https://ideone.com/yEEcgN